# R Tidy Census - Variable for Voters 18+

Tags: r, tidycensus

I have been trying to find a variable on the Tidy Census’ latest American Community Survey (ACS) variable list.

The one I’m looking for would be for all voters aged 18 and up. I have yet to find it in the list. Even if I have to combine a couple variables to make it work, that’s fine too.

I search for relevant keywords related to age, but have yet to find anything. Variables that appear with “18 years and over” have a greater specificity than what I am looking for. I may be missing something though; I’m new to Tidy Census.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding Census variables is difficult. Start here: https://data.census.gov/table?q=ACS

In table `S0101` under labels there is a `selected age categories` variable named `18 years and over`.

Searched those those keywords and found this long list. https://api.census.gov/data/2019/acs/acs1/subject/variables/

Where we find `variable` "S0101_C01_026".

> ["S0101_C01_026E","Estimate!!Total!!Total population!!SELECTED AGE CATEGORIES!!18 years and over","AGE AND SEX"],

Then we can get that variable:

```
county_data<-get_acs(geography = "county", 
                variables = "S0101_C01_026",
                cache_table=TRUE,
                year=2021)
```

county_data

> ```
> # A tibble: 3,221 × 5
>    GEOID NAME                     variable      estimate   moe
>    <chr> <chr>                    <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>
>  1 01001 Autauga County, Alabama  S0101_C01_026    44438   122
>  2 01003 Baldwin County, Alabama  S0101_C01_026   178105    NA
>  3 01005 Barbour County, Alabama  S0101_C01_026    19995    28
>  4 01007 Bibb County, Alabama     S0101_C01_026    17800    44
>  5 01009 Blount County, Alabama   S0101_C01_026    45201    75
> ```

Comment: I've used this page to find the variables I want and it's worked out well for me. You just have to scroll almost all the way down first. https://api.census.gov/data.html